# Using Open GL in an Android Widget

Tags: android, opengl-es

I can make a widget. I can draw primitives in Open GL ES with Android. (I'm just learning) But I haven't found anything on how to use Open GL ES within the Android widget framework. For starters, I just want to have a widget that will draw a triangle. (I'm targeting 2.2) Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by widget. If you are talking about app widgets (or Launcher widgets), you cannot do what you want. If you are creating a widget inside your application, use SurfaceView (API Demos has a couple of examples.)

Comment: App Widget (like the clock, weather widgets..) that users put on home and sibling screens.

Comment: You cannot use OpenGL in those widgets.